# Selling AMIs on AWS Market Place

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am currently looking at the steps on how to created and sell AMIs.

I can easily create the AMI, however I am unsure about the required architecture that is needed.  The Amazon documentation states:

- Source AMIs for AWS Marketplace MUST be provided in the us-east-1 region.

Does this mean the AMI needs to be created from an instance that is in the us-east-1 region?  As currently all my instances are in eu-west-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The created AMI must be present in the us-east-1 region.

See here for more  https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/help/201231340 , https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/help/200940380

Comment: Thank you for the links @Sathish, reading the information from them, I saw this note: 

**bold** `Once your AMI is submitted, AWS Marketplace will create cloned AMIs for each region that you have indicated that software should be available.`

If I understand this correctly, basically you can create the AMI in any region but you need to make sure the AMI is cloned to us-east-1 region (plus any other regions you select).